# How to put error bar caps on pandas series bar plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

I am trying to put error bar caps in a pandas series bar plot. Other methods I've seen have not worked.

I tried changing the capsize value or changing the value of plt.rcParams['errorbar.capsize'] or using plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')

```
s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5})
err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
plt.figure()
s.plot(kind='barh',xerr=err)
plt.show()
```

I expect to see a bar plot with error bars that have caps at the ends of the error bars, but they are just straight lines.

Comment: The reason `capsize` alone isn't working for you is that you are using some seaborn style. Refer to the last bit of the duplicate answer for that matter.

Comment: AttributeError: Unknown property capthick

Comment: I get this error if I try using the last bit of that answer. Maybe with pandas series it doesn't work the same?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I gave an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a usual pandas bar plot, it would be sufficient to specify the `capsize`. I.e.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5})
err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
plt.figure()
s.plot(kind='barh', xerr=err, capsize=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However in this case you seem to be using a seaborn style. This modifies the capthickness. So one needs to set it either through the bar's `error_kw`,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')

s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5})
err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
plt.figure()
s.plot(kind='barh', xerr=err, capsize=3, error_kw=dict(capthick=1))
plt.show()
```

or revert the change via rcParams,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.rcParams.update({"lines.markeredgewidth" : 1,
                     "errorbar.capsize" : 3})

s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5})
err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
plt.figure()
s.plot(kind='barh', xerr=err)
plt.show()
```

[image]